# layout:decorate not resolving in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have added the following html tag to a file that references `base.html`:

```
<html 
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="~{base}"
>
```

However, this fails with the following error whenever I call it:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-5] Exception processing template "register": 
An error happened during template parsing (template: "/Users/david/IdeaProjects/Greeting/src/main/resources/templates/register.html")
```

When I remove that line, the html renders fine, but it is obviously not importing the base.html template file. Here is my project structure:

```
- resources
  - templates
    - base.html
    - register.html
```

Finally, I have added this in my WebConfig:

```
private TemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    return engine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as:

```
layout:decorator="base"
```

Note that the tag is called "decorator" not "decorate".

Here are [detailed instructions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html).